# Opencv Videocapture fails to read https url videos

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I want to read HTTPS URL videos in my Ubuntu system without downloading them. I can do this in windows OS but when I try to run the same code in Ubuntu using the same opencv VideoCapture method it fails to get any frames.

Why is this so?

I have used same opencv version in both Ubuntu and Windows, can anyone guide me towards a workaround, a tutorial using which I can compile opencv and stream url videos or any other library that supports this functionality in Ubuntu ?

I have tried almost everything but with no productive result which has led me to finally ask this as a question.

```
opencv build information :

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 calib3d core dnn features2d flann gapi highgui imgcodecs imgproc java_bindings_generator ml objdetect photo python3 python_bindings_generator stitching video videoio
    Disabled:                    world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 java js python2 ts
    Applications:                -
    Documentation:               NO
    Non-free algorithms:         NO

  GUI: 
    QT:                          YES (ver 4.8.7 EDITION = OpenSource)
      QT OpenGL support:         NO
    GTK+:                        NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O: 
    ZLib:                        /lib64/libz.so (ver 1.2.3)
    JPEG:                        /opt/libjpeg-turbo/lib64/libjpeg.a (ver 62)
    WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
    PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.35)
    TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.9)
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    HDR:                         YES
    SUNRASTER:                   YES
    PXM:                         YES
    PFM:                         YES

  Video I/O:
    DC1394:                      NO
    FFMPEG:                      YES
      avcodec:                   YES (ver 58.21.104)
      avformat:                  YES (ver 58.17.101)
      avutil:                    YES (ver 56.18.102)
      swscale:                   YES (ver 5.2.100)
      avresample:                NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    v4l/v4l2:                    linux/videodev2.h

  Parallel framework:            pthreads

  Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)

  Other third-party libraries:
    Lapack:                      NO
    Eigen:                       NO
    Custom HAL:                  NO
    Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)

  OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
    Include path:                /io/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
    Link libraries:              Dynamic load

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python (ver 3.6.5)
    Libraries:                   libpython3.6m.a (ver 3.6.5)
    numpy:                       /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.3)
    packages path:               lib/python3.6/site-packages

  Python (for build):            /opt/python/cp36-cp36m/bin/python

  Java:                          
    ant:                         NO
    JNI:                         NO
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Install to:                    /io/_skbuild/linux-x86_64-3.6/cmake-install
```

Comment: Do you can capture http video with pure ffmpeg?

Comment: Yes, I can read a http video file and am able to write it to local file using ffmpeg but what I want is to read the frames without downloading the file

Comment: Try to set backend for capture: cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://...', cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)

Comment: It turns out that videocapture can get http urls but not https. Any idea what might be causing this error Ubuntu or Opencv ?

Comment: I can read https url using ffmpeg is this a cv2 build issue ?

Comment: OpenCV is writing i to console some error message? May be it need to compile ffmpeg with openssl? Or it can enable in source code

Comment: cv2.videoCapture returns boolean variable as false when cap.read() is executed and video can not be accesed as when I print cap.isOpened() it returns false. if use ffmpeg explicitly in terminal https url can be read but I can not read it using cv2.videocapture() that's why I want to know if this is a cv2 build issue.. is there any option I can enable while rebuilding cv2 from source ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be necessary. If ffmpeg was compiled with openssl but not enable it then it need to add in cap_ffmpeg.cpp from opencv/modules/videoio: av_dict_set(&d, "protocol_whitelist", "crypto", 0);

Answer (score 0):

my code is working

```
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('https://192.168.00.00:8080/video')
cv2.namedWindow('live cam', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    img_resize = cv2.resize(frame, (960, 540))
    cv2.imshow('live cam', img_resize)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```